# Juego que al preguntar devuelve pares o nones según lo que yo le conteste

Tags: java, api, string, condiciones, script

No me devuelve lo que le pido, si le digo pares, me devuelve pares, si le digo nones no hace nada. El programa me pregunta ¿pares o nones? y si le contesto pares, él me tiene que decir nones, en cambio si le digo nones el me tiene que decir pares, es un juego sencillo ya que me estoy iniciando pero no me devuelve lo que le pido

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class App {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Elige pares o nones");

        String paresNones = sc.nextLine();
        String pares = sc.nextLine();

        String nones;
        if (paresNones == pares) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido pares entonces yo elijo nones");

        }else if(paresNones == nones){
        System.out.println("Has elegido nones entonces yo elijo pares");

    } else 

    System.out.println("Elige pares o nones");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Cómo exactamente funciona tu juego? podrías poner un ejemplo gráfico de cómo funciona?

Comment: El programa me pregunta ¿pares o nones? y si le contesto pares, él me tiene que decir nones, en cambio si le digo nones el me tiene que decir pares, es un juego sencillo ya que me estoy iniciando pero no me devuelve lo que le pido.

Comment: tienes que escribir en tu texto exactamente la frase `pares` y la frase `nones`? Qué pasa si escribe otra palabra u otra cosa que no sea una de esas 2?

Comment: Si le escribo otra cosa no hace nada tampoco, debería volver a preguntar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la lógica es la que describes posteriormente, lo que debes hacer es guardar la elección del usuario en una variable y comparar esa elección con "pares" y "nones" para dar la respuesta acorde.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Elige pares o nones");

    String eleccion = sc.nextLine();

    if (eleccion.equals("pares")) {
        System.out.println("Has elegido pares entonces yo elijo nones");
    }
    if (eleccion.equals("nones")) {
        System.out.println("Has elegido nones entonces yo elijo pares");    
    }
  }
}
```

Si quieres volver a preguntar en caso de que no responda ninguna de las anteriores, una manera es incluir un bucle while después de la lectura, hasta obtener una de las respuesta válidas así:

```
while (!(eleccion.equals("pares") || eleccion.equals("nones"))) {
    System.out.println("Recuerda: elige pares o nones");
    eleccion = sc.nextLine();
}
```

|| es el operador OR (ocurre una cosa O la otra, entonces es verdadero)

! Es el operador NOT (devuelve falso si la evaluación a la derecha es verdadera, y viceversa)

Entonces la acción de ese while se puede leer como "si no ingresa pares o no ingresa nones, seguir pidiendo ingresar". Finalmente el código quedaría así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Elige pares o nones");
        String eleccion = sc.nextLine();
        while (!(eleccion.equals("pares") || eleccion.equals("nones"))) {
            System.out.println("Recuerda: elige pares o nones");
            eleccion = sc.nextLine();
        }

        if (eleccion.equals("pares")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido pares entonces yo elijo nones");
        }
        if (eleccion.equals("nones")) {
            System.out.println("Has elegido nones entonces yo elijo pares");    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso es correcto el problema es que si le pongo otra opción que no sea pares o nones no me vuelve a preguntar

Comment: Respuesta editada. Si no comprendes eso que agregué puedo explayarme más.

Comment: Lo entiendo perfectamente, no entiendo porque no lo he visto si era muy sencillo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te ha servido puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta con el tick verde a la izquierda ¡Gracias!